# Make alt/option key work as in all other applications

Tags: macos, iterm2, iterm

I'm using the alt/option key quite extensively, e.g. square brackets, curly brackets, jumping left/right etc.

The only way I've found to set alt/option to behave as it should (as in all other applications) is to set the key mapping in every profile.

I have multiple computers with at least 10 profiles each, so it's not an option to set this per each profile.

Is there any smarter option to set this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's actually really quick to do what you suggest: that is, to take the settings from one profile, and copy them across to all other existing profiles.

① Select the profile from which you want to copy your key mappings. Choose *Other Actions* at the bottom of the dialog, and then *Bulk Copy from Selected Profile* in the menu that pops up:

[image: iTerm Preferences on MacOS]

② In the options window that pops up next, click on *Keys* to indicate that these settings are the ones you wish to copy.  From the list below, select the profiles you wish to copy those settings across to.  You can do it for all ten of your profiles at once.

[image: iTerm Preferences on MacOS]